# Perl XML::Simple output nested node

Tags: perl

As input I have

```
$XML = {'node1' => {'node2' => {'node3' => {'node4'}}}};
```

then I generate the out xml

```
print(XMLout($XML, KeepRoot => 1));
```

and I get

```
<node1>
  <node2 name="node3" node4="" />
</node1>
```

How can I get this as output

```
<node1>
  <node2>
    <node3>
      <node4></node4>
    </node3>
  </node2>
</node1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML::Simple isn't actually simple to use. You are better off with [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML).

Here is an example that shows how you can find how the data structure should look.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $sample = 
"<node1>
  <node2>
    <node3>
      <node4></node4>
    </node3>
  </node2>
</node1>";

my $xs = XML::Simple->new(ForceArray => 1, KeepRoot => 1);
my $ref = $xs->XMLin($sample);

print "\n---------------\n", Dumper($ref), "\n--------------\n";

my $xml = $xs->XMLout($ref);
print "\n----------------\n";
print $xml;
```

The output produced from Data::Dumper shows the data structure.

```
---------------
$VAR1 = {
          'node1' => [
                       {
                         'node2' => [
                                      {
                                        'node3' => [
                                                     {
                                                       'node4' => [
                                                                    {}
                                                                  ]
                                                     }
                                                   ]
                                      }
                                    ]
                       }
                     ]
        };

--------------

----------------
<node1>
  <node2>
    <node3>
      <node4></node4>
    </node3>
  </node2>
</node1>
```

Without ForceArray it looks like the output you received.

Answer (score 2):

```
 perl -MXML::Simple -e '$XML = {"n1" => {"n2" => [{"n3" => [{"n4"=>[{}]}]}]}}; 
                        print(XMLout($XML, KeepRoot=>1));'
```

Gives

```
<n1>
  <n2>
    <n3>
      <n4></n4>
    </n3>
  </n2>
</n1>
```

The use of XML::Simple is discouraged. https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple